# Moving Token after getting 6 on the Dice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So currently I am doing a Ludo Game and at the moment when I get a 6 on the Dice a Red Token goes onto the Starting Position. Now I need to know how I could make the Token move after I roll the dice again. The code for the token to move is already implemented which is this:

```cs
NetworkLayer.MoveSteps(NetworkManager.MyGamePlayerId, randomDiceSide);
```

This is the coroutine which im using on the `Dice`:

```cs
    private IEnumerator RollTheDice()
    {
        int randomDiceSide = 0;
        int finalSide = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            randomDiceSide = Random.Range(1, 7);
            rend.sprite = diceSides[randomDiceSide];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }

        if(randomDiceSide == 6)
        {
            if(NetworkManager.MyGamePlayerId != "Spectator"){
            //inform everyone about this, including myself
            GameObject path = GameObject.Find("Box1");
            player.transform.position = path.transform.position;
            //NetworkLayer.MoveSteps(NetworkManager.MyGamePlayerId, randomDiceSide);
            }
            else{
                print("you cannot generate random numbers...you are the spectator");
            }     
        }

        Debug.Log(randomDiceSide);
    }
```

All I need to know is how can I make the token to move when rolling the dice again. And where can I implement a boolean probably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider implementing a class for your player. You can keep all properties related to player there, for example, position of token, token sprite, boolean `canMove` for possibility of moving, etc.

Another solution is to create a separate class for your token and keep boolean there.

And the easiest one is to store that boolean in an array in your `NetworkManager` class or in similar manager. In this case you can store all tokens properties in one place.